# Sound not playing in Titanium

Tags: ios, audio, titanium, event-listener

I have the following code to play the sound. However nothing is happening when I press the button. The sound file is located in Resource folder. Need help in this.

```
var playButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
  title:'play',
  borderRadius : 'black',
  top:40,
  right:65,
  width:50,
  height:50
})

playButton.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var sound = Titanium.Media.createSound({
        sound : "1-0.wav"
    });
    sound.play();

})
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.Sound

It shows the sound being assigned to a url param of the createSound call.

```
var player = Ti.Media.createSound({url:"sound.wav"});
player.play();
```

I'm not seeing a 'sound' param in the most recent docs, but perhaps you are using an older version of the SDK.

Comment: where to copy sound.wav file?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no sound property available for the media.

You need to use the url property instead.

```
playButton.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var sound = Ti.Media.createSound({
       url:"1.0.wav"
    });
sound.play();
})
```

Reference [Titanium Media](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.Sound)

Comment: I am not able to play file.
var sound = Ti.Media.createSound({
 url : 'bad.mp3'      //Location of the sound file
});
sound.play();
Copied the file into asset folder directly, any changes?

Comment: @BhavanaVadodariya: You need to copy the file to `Resources` folder.

Comment: I have already did, http://oi60.tinypic.com/2nb7rz6.jpg, still not working.
Giving error:  java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resources/alloy/controllers/bad.mp3

Comment: any other way through which I can play sound files(.mp3 or any other)?

Comment: @BhavanaVadodariya: from your previous comment it looks like that the sound file path need to be `Resources/alloy/controllers/bad.mp3`

Comment: yeah did that and it solved, but that was from error. Ideally it should be in asset/Resource.